# Levy's Theorem (a form of CLT for random variables with infinite variance)

Tags: probability

Possible extension to Levy's Theorem e.g., Theorem 3.8.2 of Durrett (p 186, version 5 of ``Probability: Theory and Examples").

Theorem 3.8.2 of Durrett (p 186) is, roughly speaking, a kind of form of the CLT for random variables with infinite variance: Loosely, the sum of i.i.d. random variables with a stable distribution converges in distribution to another stable distribution as the number of terms in the sum tends to infinity.
My question is: Does there exist a version where the random variables are independent but NOT identically distributed? This may often be the case in applied examples in engineering or economics? For example, is the following result true for random variables with a power law distribution (each has the same tail index)?

Theorem?

Let $\alpha$ be a constant, satisfying $0 < \alpha < 2$. $ \, $ 
Suppose $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are independent random variables drawn from distributions that
satisfy

$P(X_j > x) = c_j \, x^{-\alpha}$, where $c_j$, for each $j \geq 1$, are constants, with $0 < c_j < \infty$.

Let $S_n = X_1 + ~ \ldots ~ + X_n$.

Then there exist constants $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that as $n \rightarrow \infty$, 
$ \, $ $(S_n ~ - ~ b_n ) / a_n$ $~ \rightarrow Y$ where $Y$ has a nondegenerate stable distribution.

Does anyone know of such a result? In essence, I am hoping that one can extend Theorem 3.8.2 of Durrett analogously to how Lyapunov's form of the CLT relaxes Lindeberg's form of the CLT to variables that may have different means and variances. Does anyone have a reference, a proof or a counterexample? This is for an application - its not my homework!

Comment: There are no such distributions: it is not possible that $P(X_j \gt x) = c_j x^{-\alpha}$ for all $x.$

Comment: If you alter the (unspecified) range of $X$ to be $\geq \theta_j > 0$, your distributions will all be Pareto distributions, and you are looking for the distribution of the (normalized) sum of Pareto variates with different lower bounds, which seems to me to be extremely unlikely to converge to anything interesting or useful without further restrictions.